# Hide the navigation buttons causes a move in the surfaceView and bad response in rapid touch

Tags: android

I'm develop a video Streming app. I want to hide navigation bottons but SurfaceView position is translated from actual center to the new center.
I read about Using Immersive Full-Screen Mode but i want app work in android 4.0+. And Immersive is only for 4.4.

Furthermore, if i touch rapidly, hidding don't work fine. If I use Visibility.GONE versus Visibility.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION hidding work fine (rapidly touch), but re-center problem persists. 
Re-center movements problem occurs both with GONE and SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION.

SurfaceView is anchored to center:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="@color/Black">

    <SurfaceView 
        android:id="@+id/videoSurface"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" 
                  android:id="@+id/channelList"      
                  android:background="#2000" 
                   android:paddingLeft="5.0dip" android:paddingTop="5.0dip" android:paddingBottom="5.0dip" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="80.0dip">
        <!-- Inserted dynamically -->
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The Java Activity relevant Code:

```
public class VideoActivity extends Activity {
    ...
    //Prepare Screen (FULLSCREEN)
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    ...

    mVideoSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.videoSurface);
    mVideoSurfaceView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View paramAnonymousView, MotionEvent paramAnonymousMotionEvent) {
            Log.d("UiVisibility", "onTouch");

                VideoActivity.this.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
            return false;
        }
    });

    // Synchronize the other elements (from android docs)
    getWindow().getDecorView().setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener (new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
            Log.d("UiVisibility", "onSystemUiVisibilityChange - bool " + String.valueOf((visibility & View.GONE) == 0));
            // Note that system bars will only be "visible" if none of the
            // LOW_PROFILE, HIDE_NAVIGATION, or FULLSCREEN flags are set.
            if ((visibility & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION) == 0) {
                // TODO: The system bars are visible. Make any desired
                // adjustments to your UI, such as showing the action bar or
                // other navigational controls.
                VideoActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.channelScroll).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                getActionBar().show();
            } else {
                // TODO: The system bars are NOT visible. Make any desired
                // adjustments to your UI, such as hiding the action bar or
                // other navigational controls.
                VideoActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.channelScroll).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                getActionBar().hide();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I have solved the issue:

In Activity I define:

```
  private static int LAYOUT_FLAGS= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                                  |View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                                  |View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION;
  private static int HIDE_FLAGS=LAYOUT_FLAGS |View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                                             |View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;
```

- LAYOUT_FLAGS sets the layout as if the status bar and navigation bar are hidden. And makes the inner layout will not move when the bars are hidden or shown.
- HIDE_FLAGS Makes effective the hiding.

In onCreate()

```
...
//Prepare Screen (FULLSCREEN)
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
...
//onClick - Hide System UI (Only for hidden, show events are handler by the system)
mVideoSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.videoSurface);
    mVideoSurfaceView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("UiVisibility", "onClick");
            hideUI();
        }
});

//Synchronize my bars with System UI hidding 
getWindow().getDecorView().setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener (new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
            Log.d("UiVisibility", "onSystemUiVisibilityChange - bool " + String.valueOf((visibility & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION) == 0));
            // Note that system bars will only be "visible" if none of the
            // LOW_PROFILE, HIDE_NAVIGATION, or FULLSCREEN flags are set.
            if ((visibility & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION) == 0) {
                // The system bars are visible. Make any desired
                // adjustments to your UI
                VideoActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.channelScroll).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                //getActionBar().show();
                mIsListChannelVisible=true;
            } else {
                // The system bars are NOT visible. Make any desired
                // adjustments to your UI.
                VideoActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.channelScroll).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                //getActionBar().hide();
                mIsListChannelVisible=false;
            }
        }
});
```

Show and hide methods:

```
// Hide need a delay to wait nav bar transition is completed. (fix: too fast click fails)
private void hideUI(){
    mVideoSurfaceView.getHandler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            VideoActivity.this.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(HIDE_FLAGS);
        }
    },600);
}

private void showUI(){
    VideoActivity.this.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(0);
}
```

My custom bar is covered by the navigation bar, to fix it:
In myLayout.xml set fitSystemWindows=true

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:id="@+id/channelScroll"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >
```

It works perfect.

Comment: To show to UI in `showUI()` you really should use `setSystemUiVisibility(LAYOUT_FLAGS)` instead of `0`. This keeps the layout flags intact. This stops my `FrameLayout` with `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` which hold my video controls from jumping around and bugging out when the user shows and hides the system UI quickly. Literally spent hours trying to solve this issue until I saw your idea of having two vars (`LAYOUT_FLAGS` and `HIDE_FLAGS`)